# Can not figure out why android test is hanging

Tags: android, multithreading, integration-testing, mockito

I want to test function which opens thread and returns callback.
Every time after the first test case the second Test is hung and in log I see ApacheSDK(32004): Exception e:java.lang.NullPointerException. When I remove ~/.android file and clean the project, the error disappears but this doesn't solve the problem.
I am using CountDownLatch to make test's thread to wait.
If I will comment one of these tests, the another one runs without any problem. I really can't understand whether the problem in my code or in ADT.

```
public class HelperTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

  @Test
  public void test_A() throws Throwable {
    TestAdInfoMock info = new TestAdInfoMock();
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    when(util.execute()).thenReturn(X, Y, Z,
            T);
    final IRequest requestComplete = new IRequest() {

        @Override
        public void onReceiveInfoCompleted() {
            assertNull(“message”, …);
            assertNull("message", …);
            latch.countDown();
         }
    };

    //The requestData opens thread with AsyncTask
    Helper.requestData(context, requestComplete); 
    boolean await = latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertTrue(await);
}

 @Test
 public void test_B() throws Throwable {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    when(util.execute()).thenReturn(X, Y, Z,
            T);

     final IRequest requestComplete = new IRequest() {

        @Override
        public void onReceiveInfoCompleted() {
            assertNull(“message”, …);
            assertNull("message", …);
            latch.countDown();
         }
    };        
    //The requestData opens thread with AsyncTask
    Helper.requestData(context, requestComplete); //

    boolean await = latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertTrue(await);
}


@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    clearPreferences();
}

void clearPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("global", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.remove(KEY!);
    editor.remove(KEY2);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

Any suggestions and comments are appreciated.

Edit:

To figure out the problem I started to do primitive analyze: iteration.

when when removed the clearPreferences() method from tearDown method, all test worked fine. 
But still I don't understand why the clearPreferences method should hang the testing.

Answer (score 0):

When using a CountDownLatch in Android, problems usually occur when you are calling the countDown and await on the same Thread.

I do not know IRequest, but a callback like onReceiveInfoCompleted usually runs on the main Thread:

```
@Override
        public void onReceiveInfoCompleted() {
            assertNull(“message”, …);
            assertNull("message", …);
            latch.countDown();
         }
```

and thus on the same Thread you are calling await on. You will however never reach countdown as you called await on the Thread first.

Comment: why do you think that onReceiveInfoCompleted runs on the main Thread?